# Certificate is not showing up in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssl-certificate, database

I need to say first that I am not a DBA and so, my problem is getting SQL Server Configuration Manager to recognize a certificate.  I have 3 SQL Instances I work on, 2 are on the same network, the other is on a completely separate network.  The one on a different network worked fine after giving permission to the cert.  The 2 on the same network however just do not want to work.  Those 2 are SQL Server 2008, the other is 2014.  Each Instance is on a physically different server, which are running Server 2008 R2 as an OS.  The 2014 Instance is running on Server 2012.  I have looked at the following links for help [SqlServer 2008 How to correctly install/configure SSL certificate to require encrypted connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/116466/sqlserver-2008-how-to-correctly-install-configure-ssl-certificate-to-require-enc), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342769/sql-server-cannot-find-certificate and I have also followed all steps in this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316898 .  I verified the certs are valid according to the last link.

I have also followed through the sqldude's tutorial (I can't find the link currently) and made the registry edit.  Now on 1 of the 2008 instances that did NOT make a difference, on the other 2008 instance it caused sql to stop working.  The error logs then say the cert is invalid, which I don't understand considering according the KB article I linked it is.

I can't show any of the error log information, or the certificate information as the 2 Instances giving me problems are on a controlled private network, that is not connected to the Internet.

Can some one please help me, I've spent a lot of time googling this to no avail.  Thank you for any help.